# Append div and class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to arrange news items in mvc4 razor  with repetitive listing which wraps every two articles in a div class "news-group clearfix" and add a css element "last"  to the  second article class as shown below.

```
<div id="main-content">

  <div class="news-group clearfix">
     <article class="news static-page">...</article>
     <article class="news static-page last">...</article>
     </div>

    **<div class="news-group clearfix">**
      <article class="news-container news static-page">...</article>
     <article class="news-container static-page **last**">...</article>
     **</div>**

    **<div class="news-group clearfix">**
      <article class="news-container news static-page">...</article>
     <article class="news-container static-page **last**">...</article>
     **</div>**
</div>
```

I have been able to add the "last" using the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('article.news-container:even').addClass('last');
});
</script>
```

I need help on how to encapsulate  the repeating units of 2 articles with `<div class=news-group clearfix><div>` on iteration in razor view.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think that the tags [tag:css], [tag:asp.net-mvc-4] and [tag:razor] aren't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can do something like this

```
$('article.news-container:odd').each(function(){
       $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll("<div class="news-group clearfix"></div>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response.  I have tried your solution it is elegant but it ignores the first article.  Are you able to help further?

Comment: Thanks changing the :odd to even fixed the problem  thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY**

```
$('.news-group.clearfix').append('<div>hello</div>').addClass('last');

**OR**

    $('.news-group.clearfix').addClass('last').append('<div>hello</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks  I selected the other answer and did not test your solution